# MyCraft download error

Tags: 14.04, games

Hi I purchased and attempted to download MyCraft, but there was an error in the download.  No option to attempt another download, just offer to buy again.  Suggestions?

Comment: How did you attempt to download it? (and what did you use - Firefox, Chrome, wget, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened the same to me about 5 hours ago', I have contacted the developer who replied immediately giving me a reference to this link: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-center
Anyway, after visiting the link I see that there is no relation. 
I have replied back asking for an alternative download since that the Paypal payment went through. I am still waiting for his response.

The Game was purchased through the Ubuntu Software Centre, after paying with Paypal I was redirect to the Software Centre again but the download/install never happened so I guess the bug is in the Ubuntu Software Centre or in the link with the repository were the software resides.

Answer (score 2):

FYI the original game is free here: http://www.michaelfogleman.com/craft/

MyCraft was posted by a different developer to the Ubuntu store, so don't expect good support from him/her.